# Google analytics bounce rate of 150%

Tags: analytics

I have a page on my site which received 339 pageviews, 265 unique pageviews and a bounce rate of 150%.
Do you have any idea why is this happening?

P.S. The selected period is current day. Could it be because the analytics algorithm didn't finish all the calculations?

Answer (score 0):

Do you see such bounce rate for that page if you review previous dates? If not sometimes the free version of GA depending on volume to your site might be delayed calculating for some metrics. When viewing the data for that page today. I assume you assessed it 24th of May?

m